# Highlighting AND link_to with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have an application where I want to highlight some words, and have some stuff happen onclick of those same words. I'm pretty new to programming but have gained a lot of confidence with Ruby, so I'm trying to do all with ruby if I can. I can get it to highlight like this:

```
<%= highlight(line, @words_to_highlight) %>
```

and I can get it to link_to like this:

```
<%= highlight(line, @words_to_highlight) { |match| link_to(match, story_path) }%>
```

My problem is that I can get it to only do one or the other (`highlight` or `link_to`), but not both, and so I'd like to know if there's a way to do both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've overridden default behaviour of `highlight`. Your code basically says "turning words into links IS the way I want to highlight them". If you want the visual effects as well, do [what `highlight` does](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c684f4f3da5665f3571307e4eabdcdeedf7b5aa2/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb#L143-L144) (surround match with some markup). So something like this, perhaps:

```
highlight(line, @words_to_highlight) { |match| link_to("<mark>#{match}</mark>", story_path) }
```

Comment: I ended up copying and pasting the original function and putting it in my own project, renaming it, and changed the regex expression that it uses in order to identify word boundaries. Works great! I'm currently trying to figure out how to wrap each highlighted word with a special class name in order to implement some jquery/javascript functionality.